# How can I remove the grid border from a Bokeh plot?

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm trying to create an interactive bokeh plot that does not have any interface whatsoever. I found a way to remove the tools and the gridlines, but I cannot find any way to remove the grey grid border.

This is a minimal working example that illustrates what I'm after:

```
from bokeh.models import Range1d
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show

output_file('test.html')

p = figure(width=300, height=100, toolbar_location=None)
p.rect(x=0.5*60, y=0.5, width=60, height=1)

p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
p.ygrid.grid_line_color = None
p.axis.visible = False
p.x_range = Range1d(0, 100)
p.toolbar.active_drag = None

show(p)
```

The result looks as follows:

[image: Minimal working example.]

As you can see it still includes a slight grey line that I would like to get rid of. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
p.outline_line_color = None
```